# Can't trigger a wheel in azure data factory

Tags: azure-databricks, python-wheel, azure-data-factory

I created and tested multiple times a python wheel on my local machine and on Azure Databricks as a Job and it worked fine.

Now, I'm trying to create an Azure Data Factory Pipeline that triggers the wheel stored in Azure Databricks (`dbfs:/..`) everytime a new file is stored in a blob storage container.

The wheel takes a parameter (`-f`) and the values is new file name. I passed it to the wheel using `argparse` inside the script.py and parameters section of databricks job in the previous tests.

I created the pipeline and setted two parameters `param` and `value` that I want to pass to the wheel whose values are `-f` and `new-file.txt`. [See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GGry.png)

Then I created a Databricks Python file in ADF workspace and paste wheel path into `Python file` section. Now I'm wondering if this is the right way to do this.

I passed the parametes in the way you can see in the image below and I didn't add any library as I've already attacched the wheel in the upper section (I've tried to add the wheel also as library but notthing changed). [See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk4LS.png)

I've created the trigger for blob storage and I've checked that in the trigger json file the parameters exists. Trying to trigger the pipeline I received this error: [See image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AL3k3.png)

I checked if there are errors in code and I changed to UTF-8 the encoding as suggested in other questions of the community but notthing changes.

At this point, I think that I didn't trigger correctly the blob storage or the wheel can't be attached in the way I've done. I didn't add other resources in the workspace, hence I've only Databricks Python file.

Any advice is really appreciate,
thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal is to launch a wheel package from a databricks python notebook using Azure data factory and calling the notebook via the activity python databricks.

I think the problem that you are facing would be when calling the python wheel from the notebook.

Here is an example that I tried to use which is close to your needs and it worked fine.

1. I created a hello.py script and put it on the path `/dbfs/FileStore/jars/`

Here is the content of hello.py (just prints the provided arguments)

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', help='file', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
print('You provided the value : ', args.f)
```

2. I created a python notebook on databricks that takes arguments and passes them to the hello.py script.
   This code defines the parameter that the notebook can take (which refers to the parameters you pass via Azure Data Factory while calling the activity databricks)

```py
    dbutils.widgets.text("value", "new_file.txt")  
    dbutils.widgets.text("param", "-f")
```

This code retrieves the parameters passed to the databricks notebook

```py
param = dbutils.widgets.get("param")
value = dbutils.widgets.get("value")
```

And finally we call the python hello.py script to execute our custom code as follows :

```
!python /dbfs/FileStore/jars/hello.py $param $value
```

Pay attention to the ! at the begining.

Hope this helps your needs and don't forget to mark the answer :) .

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My goal originally was to use only the wheel in ADF but if this is not possible use a support notebook or python script to run the wheel it's ok. Previously, I created a wheel that contains the whole code and I loaded it in Azure Databricks Job with gives me the possibility to pass the parameters. Now, I've a question.. how do you use the wheel in your example?

Comment: I have never done it using the wheel directly, but this doc explains how to achieve it https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/jobs/how-to-use-python-wheels-in-workflows.html#step-5-create-a-databricks-job-to-run-the-python-wheel
So it is possible to do.

Comment: I've seen but it's not what I need. I think that's not possible to run a wheel on ADF directly and I found two possible solutions: run __main__.py (that contains the whole code) as Python Activity or create a pipeline that calls Databricks Job API.

Comment: ADF is more likely an orchestration tool, so running a wheel with only ADF doesn't seem possible for now, I don't know what your wheel does but using databricks to only run a small tasks especially using only python with no spark involved seems expensive. I would advise you to use either an azure function that runs your wheel / code or use a logic app with a container instance having as init script your code/wheel. Then call either the az function or the logic app from ADF using REST activity and passing your parameters in the body of your request.